# Bootcamp startup failure after Mojave upgrade

Tags: bootcamp, mojave

I recently upgraded my 2015 Macbook Pro Retina to Mac OS X Mojave 10.14.2, after which my previously functional Bootcamp Windows 10 stopped working. I can see "Bootcamp" as a startup disk option:

[image]

And from the desktop I can see that my files exist in the Bootcamp partition:

[image]

When I restart my MacbookPro while holding down the 'option' key, Windows 10 does not display as a startup option. If I force the Startup Disk to Bootcamp in the System Preferences and restart, I get the "No Bootable Device" screen.

[image]

Any ideas what might be wrong here and how to remedy. I would like to avoid reinstalling Windows if at all possible.

Comment: No, it is a 2015 Macbook Pro Retina

Comment: How did you make the image you posted? It is to perfect.

Comment: Which image are you referring to?

Comment: The last image. I have seen were a picture of the screen was taken, then posted. I do not think you can capture the screen any other way. Your image just looks as if it was created some other way.

Comment: You're correct, it's not a screen capture. I just found the image on Google. It was easier than taking a picture.